# Flux of electric field through disk

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, physics

Say we have a point charge $+q$ at the origin from which it emanates an electric field
$$\mathbf E=\frac{kq}{r^2}\hat{\mathbf r}\ .$$
Now suppose we want to calculate the flux of this electric field through a surface defined by the intersection of a cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and the plane $z=z_0>0$, namely,
$$
\mathcal S:\left\{
\begin{align}
&x^2+y^2\leq z_0^2\\
&z=z_0
\end{align}
\right.$$
with normal vector $\mathbf n=\hat{\mathbf z}$.

Then, in spherical coordinates, we'd find this:
$$\Phi=\oint_{\mathcal S}\mathbf E\cdot\mathrm d\mathbf S=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{kq}{r^2}\underbrace{(\hat{\mathbf r}\cdot\hat{\mathbf z})}_{\cos\theta}r^2\sin\theta\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm d\Phi=kq\underbrace{\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm d\Phi}_{2\pi}\underbrace{\int_0^{\pi/4}\sin\theta\cos\theta\,\mathrm d\theta}_{1/4}=\frac{\pi}{2}kq.$$
The thing is when I do the same in cylindrical coordinates I get something different:
$$\begin{align}
\Phi=\oint_{\mathcal S}\mathbf E\cdot\mathrm d\mathbf S&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{z_0}\frac{kq}{\rho^2+z_0^2}\underbrace{(\hat{\mathbf r}\cdot\hat{\mathbf z})}_{\cos\theta}\rho\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\Phi\\
&=2\pi kq\int_0^{z_0}\frac{\rho\cos\theta}{\rho^2+z_0^2}\,\mathrm d\rho\\
&=2\pi kqz_0\underbrace{\int_0^{z_0}\frac{\rho}{(\rho^2+z_0^2)^{3/2}}\,\mathrm d\rho}_{\frac{2-\sqrt 2}{2z_0}}=(2-\sqrt 2)\pi kq\ (?),
\end{align}$$
where we used the fact
$$\cos\theta=\frac{z_0}{\sqrt{z_0^2+\rho^2}}.$$
So where did I commmit a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is quite wrong. The element of surface area on the plane $z=z_0$ is certainly not the element of surface area on the sphere. Note that we have $r\cos\theta=z_0$, so $\rho=z_0\tan\theta$ and $\rho\,d\rho=z_0^2\tan\theta\sec^2\theta\,d\theta$. When you multiply by $\cos\theta/r^2$, you will get the integral of $\sin\theta$, I believe.

Comment: I'm certain it has to do with me using the habitual spherical surface differential, without thinking because if I were to use the definition it'd give the same as you:
$$\mathbf x=\left\{\begin{align}
&x=z_0\tan\theta\cos\Phi\\
&y=z_0\tan\theta\sin\Phi\\
&z=z_0
\end{align}\right\}\implies \mathrm dS=||\partial_\theta\mathbf x\wedge \partial_\Phi\mathbf x||\mathrm d\theta\mathrm d\Phi=z_0^2\tan\theta\sec^2\theta\mathrm d\theta\mathrm d\Phi$$

Comment: Yes. I thought about writing it out explicitly with differential forms, but decided it wouldn’t be any more enlightening. :)